# Can't connect to college WiFi even after changing the MAC address

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, firewall, mac-address, xiaomi-redmi-note-4g

First of all this is completely for education purpose, there is no intension to access college Internet without official permissions.

So In my college, WiFi is only accessible via laptops. Students have initially registered their laptop's MAC address to the college, and they have given local IP addresses to each student to connect to WiFi using their laptops.

So first I've changed my MAC address of my rooted phone (Red MI Note 3) and then configured the WiFi, as I'm doing in my laptop, but this only connects my Android device to the WiFi, but can't load the student login page on the mobile phon.

So what possible firewalls or blockers are they using to block only mobile devices even if they have same MAC address as the laptop?

Is there any way to show Android device as laptop to the WiFi router? So that It allow access to mobile phones?

I've seen [this post from XDA Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2685563) but no helpful answers.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is only guessing from this perspective, as there might be several reasons.

First you should check with a simple `ping` or similar that the network is working.

If this is successfull any you try to open the login page with your browser it might be possible, that your university checks your browser's http request for your operating system or other signs, that you are using a smartphone and no laptop.

Comment: So can we install browser which does not reveals it's identity(Android or Laptop)?

Comment: Basically it is the UA string you want to set [reference](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent). It seems, that there are addons for e.g. [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/android/addon/custom-user-agent-string/) but I have not tried them.